# Nginx proxy server with multiple docker container apps

Tags: docker, nginx, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have an Alfresco Share application and multiple custom applications that are all connected. Now I have to connect them all with the `nginx` proxy server so that all of them run on port 80. I am experiencing 404 error with my custom apps (share runs fine). All of the applications are docker containers.

**My Dockerfile (for nginx):**

```
FROM nginx:latest

ARG SHARE_HOST 
ARG APP_HOST

COPY default.conf.template /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template

RUN envsubst '${SHARE_HOST}, ${APP_HOST}' < /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**My default.conf.template**

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name example.com;

  location /app {
    proxy_pass http://${APP_HOST}:3000;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://${SHARE_HOST}:8080;
  }

}
```

**My docker build command:**

```
docker build --build-arg SHARE_HOST=alfresco-share --build-arg APP_HOST=app_container -t documan-nginx-redirect .
```

`alfresco-share` and `app_container` are the names of the running containers

All containers run fine and they are all in the same network. Nginx container is also in the same network.

Share application loads fine (the URL is localhost/share/page/admin/dashboard as expected), but when i type localhost/app in the URL, it throws 404 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What webserver return 404 on localhost/app? Nginx as reserve proxy or your app webserver? Did you try add slash in `location /app/`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:

```
location /app/ {
  proxy_pass http://${APP_HOST}:3000/;
}
```